# Update Information from API with a RefreshControl

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pull-to-refresh

I am following [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol) example trying to create a refresh control, I want the user to be able to refresh the page and update the information from the API.
At the moment the page loads one time when you initially load the page and the "Pull to refresh" just waits 2 seconds.
I've tried so many things like creating an API function to fetch the data or making the request inside the onRefresh() function none of these worked..

What do I need to change in my code to get the data updated when the user refreshes the page?

Code:

```
const wait = (timeout) => {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
 });
}

function HomeScreen() {

const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
const [view, setview] = useState('');
const tableHead =  ['Room Number', 'Created at', 'Type'];

const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
setRefreshing(true);

wait(2000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));
}, []);

fetch('https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/getrooms')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => setview(data))

const tableData = [];
const ap = view.split('(');
for (let i = 0; i < ap.length - 1; i += 3) 
{
    const rowData = [];
    for (let j = i; j < i + 3; j += 1) 
    {
        rowData.push(ap[j]);
    }
    tableData.push(rowData);
}
return (
<View style={{flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8'}}>
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight}}>
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
    }
  >
  <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
    <Row data={tableHead} style={{height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff'}}/>
    <Rows data={tableData} style={{margin: 6}}/>
  </Table>
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
</View>
 );
}
```

Comment: under onRefresh 'wait' is dummy code, you need to call the 'fetch' again. Check example [here](https://medium.com/enappd/refreshcontrol-pull-to-refresh-in-react-native-apps-dfe779118f75)